# Threaded plotting in Visual Studio C++ with Windows Forms

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, forms

I'm writing an application using Visual Studio C++ 2010 to perform Data Acquisition and plot this information in real-time.  I'm using Windows Forms to create the GUI.  I am taking data from both the serial port and a DAQ card (which I have libraries for and have used) and want to plot them real-time.  I've done this before in Python, but I must use another library which is done in C++ so I can't use Python this time around.

My idea was to have the serial port and daq card in separate threads acquiring data and then sending updated information to the main program to update the plot with the new data. I have finally gotten threading to work correctly, but what I can't seem to figure out is how to update the plot from inside the thread, as what I have causes a crash.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#pragma once
#include <math.h>

namespace PlotUpdate {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Threading;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
        th1 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &Form1::th1Method));
    }

    delegate void UpdatePlot();
    UpdatePlot^ myDelegate;

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
protected: 

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;
private: System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Chart^  chart1;
         Thread ^th1;

 #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::ChartArea^  chartArea1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::ChartArea());
        System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Series^  series1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Series());
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->chart1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::Chart());
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->chart1))->BeginInit();
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(291, 369);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->button1->Text = L"button1";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
        // 
        // chart1
        // 
        chartArea1->Name = L"ChartArea1";
        this->chart1->ChartAreas->Add(chartArea1);
        this->chart1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(32, 30);
        this->chart1->Name = L"chart1";
        series1->ChartArea = L"ChartArea1";
        series1->ChartType = System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::SeriesChartType::Line;
        series1->Name = L"Series1";
        series1->XValueMember = L"xvals";
        series1->YValueMembers = L"yvals";
        this->chart1->Series->Add(series1);
        this->chart1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(669, 314);
        this->chart1->TabIndex = 1;
        this->chart1->Text = L"chart1";
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(778, 415);
        this->Controls->Add(this->chart1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"Form1";
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->chart1))->EndInit();
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

    }
 #pragma endregion
static double time = 0.0;

private: System::Void th1Method()
         {
             for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
             {
                 this->chart1->Series["Series1"]->Points->AddXY(time, sin(time));
                 time += 0.1;
                 Thread::Sleep(1);
             }
         }

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             th1->Start();
         }
};
 }
```

The code compiles and runs, until I start the thread, and it crashes.  I know, I can't update the GUI from another process, so I don't really know how I am supposed to do this.  I have tried (And I apologize for not having sample code) to create a temporary Collection of DataPoint Objects and then update the plot using a TimerEvent, but I ran into issues of not being able to use this-> notation inside a static method of the class.

Any hints/tips/advice for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm wrong, you're trying to modify the UI from within a thread that is not the UI thread, which is an error.

If this is the case, you should use the BeginInvoke method of your Form to execute code from within the UI thread.

I'm unfamiliar with C++/CLI + WinForms code, so I am unable to provide you with a code correction, but in C#, it would have been something like:

```
private void th1Method()
     {
         for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
         {
             this.BeginInvoke
             ((Action)(
                () =>
                {
                   this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(time, sin(time));
                   time += 0.1;
                }
             )) ;

             Thread.Sleep(1);
         }
     }
```

Note the BeginInvoke call, which takes here a lambda function (of type Action, meaning no parameters, and no return value). This lambda function will be queued in the UI thread, and executed later, in the UI thread.

For more information about BeginInvoke, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx

Comment: I've looked at Invoke, and it will most likely work at least for updating the plots, but I do wonder now, is how to access class methods and members from inside the threaded method?

Comment: @Nathaniel Hayes : `Invoke` will block your working thread until the UI is updated which is probably not what you want (you don't want your working thread being blocked by some UI action, don't you?). `BeginInvoke` will let the UI thread update itself when available, all the while freeing your working thread. In most (if not all) of the cases, I would use `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: @Nathaniel Hayes : `th1Method` is a non static private method of the class, so it has access to `this`. The C# code above uses a lambda function, which captures the `this` pointer, and uses it to access its data. So everything is Ok. I guess you should be able to do the same in C++/CLI (using a Lambda in Visual C++ 2010, at least), and if not, I guess you can use a simple delegate/callback, whatever, to do the trick). As I never really used C++/CLI, and as I don't have access to a Windows platform at home, I can't really tell you much more. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the help, up until I wrote something that crashed my computer so hard it destroyed my source code file, everything was working dandy.  It wasn't until I tried to implement other tools that it became broken.